# Where is the exception info for WebSocket.ReceiveAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm seeing various exception types being thrown by calls to `WebSocket.ReceiveAsync` (`HttpListenerException`, `WebsocketException`) but the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket.receiveasync) for the `ReceiveAsync` method makes no mention of what exceptions might be thrown.

Where can I find exception information for `WebSocket.ReceiveAsync` ?

Comment: That's an abstract method, it can't throw anything

Comment: You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help isolate the issue.  One of the following can happen 1) The server is not returning any data.  2) The server is returning a response that is not 200 OK 3) The server is returning a response with 200 OK and the data inside the response has issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [an abstract method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket.receiveasync?view=netcore-3.1), it can't throw anything. The implementations in the concrete classes, [ClientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.receiveasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_WebSockets_ClientWebSocket_ReceiveAsync_System_ArraySegment_System_Byte__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and (for .NET Framework only) [AspNetWebSocket.ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.websockets.aspnetwebsocket.receiveasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_WebSockets_AspNetWebSocket_ReceiveAsync_System_ArraySegment_System_Byte__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) show that the methods can throw *InvalidOperationException* or *ObjectDisposedException*